# Importing Excel sheet formated date and time data into C++ program

Tags: excel, datetime

I am using open source library XLNT to import Excel data into my C++ program.

```
 1)  Date  2/21/2019 in excel sheet is interpreted as 43517 in C++ program

 2)  Time  5:30:00  is interpreted as 0.229167 in C++ program
```

On the Excel sheet, both of the columns are date and time formatted.
I have no idea how these parameter values are deduced. Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## UNDERSTANDING TIME/DATE IN EXCEL

Excel stores the date as an integer. It is the count of the number of days since January 0, 1900. So 1 is January 1st 1900.  (I believe on Mac's the reference year is 1905 but I could be wrong).  So all dates in excel are simply integers with some special formatting applied to display them in some manner we are used to seeing.  Time on the other hand is stored a % of a day or if you prefer decimal of a day.  0.5 represent half a day or lunch.  So if you need to just find the date from a mixed time date, you need to strip off just the integer portion.  Conversely if you just need the time, you just need to strip of the decimal portion.

## DEMONSTRATION

1)  Open up excel
2)  in a cell enter 0 and then in another 1, then 2 etc.
3)  Change the format of the cell from General to Date and note how the date relates to the integers and how the change in integers relates to the change in date.

43517 is the number of days since January 0 1900.

Comment: Right, Base date is window 1900. But how to get the figure 43517?